# find index of a dataframe that is of a specific datatype

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I read in a excel file where time/date based entries there

```python
df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx)
```

then I set the index to the column that holds the date

```python
df.set_index('Date',inplace=True)
```

unfortunately some entries in this column are not a date.
I did not find a satisfying solution for the question how to find them.

I did it straight forward, but I thought there must be a more panda like way.

```python
for i in df.index:
    if not isinstance(i, pd.Timestamp):
        df[df_all.index == i]
        # here would be the place to do something
```

Comment: Could you include a small sample of the dataframe once read in from the test.xlsx file?

Answer (score 0):

To check the datatype of the objects in all columns, just type
`df.dtypes`

For a specific column, type
`df[column_name].dtype`

To test each object in the series, use

```
df['data type'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: 'date' if type(x)==pd.Timestamp else 'not date')
```

if the date is not in the index
or

```
df['data type'] = df.index.apply(lambda x: 'date' if type(x)==pd.Timestamp else 'not date')
```

if the date is in the index

Answer (score 0):

Without setting the index you can create a boolean mask to check if a row in the 'Date' column is actually a date or not, and then maybe split the dataframe into two.

```
mask = df['test'].apply(lambda x: True if (type(x)==pd.datetime or type(x)==pd.Timestamp) else False)

date_df = df[mask]
nondate_df = df[~mask]
```